# After virtual machine reboot File Share mounted drive disconnected

Tags: powershell, azure-sdk-.net

I am mounting azure file share drive in virtual machine using .netSDK RunPowerShell method. Drive has been created successfully but whenever I restart the virtual machine my drive automatically disconnected. I am using below powershell command :

```
cmd.exe /C "cmdkey /add:`"test.file.core.windows.net`" /user:`"Azure\admin`" /pass:`"*************************`""
New-PSDrive -Name V -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\test.file.core.windows.net\amazefileshare" -Persist
```

i want my file share drive should be always available.

Comment: Add `-Scope 'Global'` after `-Persist`

Comment: @Daniel I am using below command but still same issue :  New-PSDrive -Name I -PSProvider FileSystem -Root "\\amazedcstore.file.core.windows.net\amazefileshare" -Persist -Scope 'Global'

Comment: Have you found a solution to persist the drive ? I am facing the same issue with the same configuration